# PHP and ODBC query in a while loop

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to add a query in a while loop using odbc in php.

Everytime that I try to add a query in a while loop when using odbc, the apache process is taking all the cpu performance and then, I have to kill it manually and let the watchdog restart it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Include DB configs
require_once( "dbconfig.inc" );

// Microsoft SQL Server Driver
$link = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;Server=$server;Database=$database;", $username, $password) or die ("Can't connect to MS SQL Server");

// Query the tickets
$query = odbc_exec($link, "
    SELECT
        TicketID,
        ...
    FROM
        ...
    WHERE
        ...
") or die ( "<p>".odbc_errormsg() );

// While loop
while($data = odbc_fetch_array($query)){

    // Define variables
    $ticketID = $data['TicketID'];

    // Now check how many comments that are in the ticket
    $queryCnt = odbc_exec($link, "
    SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS NumOfComments
    FROM
        ...
    WHERE
        TicketID = '" . $ticketID . "'
    ") or die ( "<p>".odbc_errormsg() );

    // Add returned count in the variable
    $num = odbc_fetch_array($queryCnt);
    $numOfComments = $num['NumOfComments'];

    // Print result
    echo "Ticket: " . $ticketID . " is containing " . $numOfComments . " comments.\n";
}
// Close DB
odbc_close($link);

?>
```

This is probably a problem with odbc itself since I always do this with mysql and I never faced this issue.

Comment: Can't you just query for both pieces of information at the same time and get rid of the loop entirely?

Comment: I already triend with a subquery within an inner join, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't a subquery here and you probably want a left join in case there are no comments. You didn't provide much detail to go on but something like this should be close.

```
select t.TicketID
    , COUNT(c.*) as NumComments
from Ticket t
left join Comments c on c.TicketID = t.TicketID
group by t.TicketID
```